# Webservice call on current displayed fragment viewpager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have view pager with 5 fragments.
On all the fragments I have 5 different web services to call.
When the app is launched all the 5 fragments web services are triggered.
Where as only the current displayed fragment's web service should be called.

How to fix this? What is the solution for it?

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new AppFragment1());
    adapter.addFragment(new AppFragment2());
    adapter.addFragment(new AppFragment3());
    adapter.addFragment(new AppFragment4());
    adapter.addFragment(new AppFragment5());

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The ViewPager creates current fragment and the next one by default. In your case I think you set PageOffsetLimit to 5 that's why all your fragments are created. A way to solve this problem is to add a listener to your ViewPager (onPageChanged) so you know in which fragment you are.

Comment: I have not set the PageOffsetLimit. My webservice call is on each fragment's oncreateview.